# Saving array of structs to shared memory

Tags: c, shared-memory

I'm trying to create a piece of shared memory that holds an array of structs. In my current code when i run it i get a segmentation fault. I think I may need to use memcpy but am severely stuck at the moment. Any help would be mch appreciated...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "header.h"


int main()
{
    key_t key = 1234;
    int shmid;
    int i = 1;

    struct companyInfo * pdata[5];

    strcpy(pdata[0]->companyName,"AIB");
    pdata[0]->sharePrice = 11.02;
    strcpy(pdata[1]->companyName,"Bank Of Ireland");
    pdata[1]->sharePrice = 10.02;
    strcpy(pdata[2]->companyName,"Permanent TSB");
    pdata[2]->sharePrice = 9.02;
    strcpy(pdata[3]->companyName,"Bank Od Scotland");
    pdata[3]->sharePrice = 8.02;
    strcpy(pdata[4]->companyName,"Ulster Bank");
    pdata[4]->sharePrice = 7.02;



    int sizeOfCompanyInfo = sizeof(struct companyInfo);

    int sizeMem = sizeOfCompanyInfo*5;

    printf("Memory Size: %d\n", sizeMem);

    shmid = shmget(key, sizeMem, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
    if(shmid == -1)
    {
        perror("shmget");       
        exit(1);
    }

    *pdata = (struct companyInfo*) shmat(shmid, (void*) 0, 0);
    if(*pdata == (struct companyInfo*) -1)
    {
        perror("schmat error");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("name is %s and %f . \n",pdata[0]->companyName,pdata[0]->sharePrice);

    exit(0);

}
```

the header.h file is as follows...

```
struct companyInfo
{
    double sharePrice;
    char companyName[100];
};
```

Comment: Where in your code does the seg fault occur? Can you step through with a debugger or even just put `printf()` statements in to see at least where the crash occurs?

Comment: It doesnt seem to like me assigning values to the array, when i strcpy into pdata[1] the segmentation fault occurs. i found it by throwing in printfs

Comment: Then it sounds like `pdata[1]` wasn't initialized properly. Fortunately, there are a couple answers below that explain how to fix that.

Comment: You have two answers that point out the problem.  I would accept hmjd's answer because it is more complete and provides code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct companyInfo * pdata[5];
```

contains an array of 5 uninitialized pointers. You need too allocate memory for each element in the array before using them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    pdata[i] = malloc(sizeof(companyInfo));
}
```

or just declare an array of `struct companyInfo` as there does not appear to be any need for dynamic allocation:

```
struct companyInfo pdata[5];
```

Comment: thanks. using malloc helped a lot and got rid of the segmentation fault.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't make the shared memory work.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660503/c-memory-sharing-across-2-programs

Answer (score 3):

`pdata` is a table of pointers so you need to create each `struct companyInfo` using malloc before being able to access them.